# MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: security_users_detail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I have many topics about this issue and still I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong:

I have two models, with the following relations:

- securty_user_rb:

  ```
  attr_accessible ...(some fields)
                  :security_users_detail

  has_one :security_users_detail, dependent: :destroy
  ```
- security_users_detail.rb

  ```
  attr_accessible ...(some fields)

  belongs_to :security_user
  ```

and in the security_users_controlller.rb I am doing this in the new action:

```
@security_user = SecurityUser.new(params[:security_user])
@security_user.build_security_users_detail(security_users_detail: SecurityUsersDetail.new)
```

Why I am not able to build the connection and I am getting

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: security_users_detail

error as I have  attr_accessible:security_users_detail in the model?

**EDIT:**

I have try to comment the following line in my applicatin.rb file in order to check if the issue will be resolved:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the same error again (after restarting the server), so I suppose my problem is connected with some other thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was caused by a validations in my *details* model - I have validations that are checking both the format and the presence of some of the fields, so apparently rails did not allowed me to created object with empty fields.

To fix this I have to used *validate:false*.

I have lost a lot of time reading about rails defaults like

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

and the use of attr_accessible, but it seems that failed validations can threw the same

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes

error.